# ayuda tengo un error al consumir api desde ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, api

el navegador me bota este error al tratar de consumir API, no se que puede ser:

> Failed to load
>   https://bitscoinmarketcap.com/ws/v1/ticker/?coinName=bitcoin: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

mi código:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://bitscoinmarketcap.com/ws/v1/ticker/?coinName=bitcoin',
 type: "get",
 dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(recursos) {
 console.log(recursos)
})
.fail(function() {
console.log("error api");
});
```

Comment: Ya se han realizado [algunas preguntas sobre el tema en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin+ajax) y tienen respuesta. ¿Has probado las soluciones que se sugieren? ¿Cómo no te funcionan? Lee [ask] para más información y edita la pregunta.

Comment: si pero ninguna me funciono gracias!!

Comment: Se están bloqueando las llamadas desde tu host. Si estás trabajando en localhost instala [esta extensión en Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) y debería dejarte hacer la conexión. Una vez subas el proyecto a un dominio debería dejarte de aparecer ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

Econtre esta solución no sé que tan óptima sea, pero funciono al error que me salia, coloque este código en mi función en php y a la hora de hacer una peticion desde ajax  me boto la información

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');  
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');   
}  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {  

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))  
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");  

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))  
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");  
}
```